# How to avoid posting in database the same value php

Tags: php

I have a problem here with break and loops things in php.I have an input type, if I give the id 2 for ex, if there is 2 in db then only "You liked this url already" should be appear.This works. If I give then id 3 it says "Data added".Good for now.But if I enter again id 3 it says:

```
Data added!You liked this url already
```

and a new value of 3 is posting in the db.How to avoid this? Here is my function:

```
<form method="post">
    Url id: <input type="text" name="urlid" id="urlid">
    <input type="submit" name="givelikes" value="Give Likes">
    <br />
    <br />

</form>
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['givelikes'])){

        $urlid = $_POST['urlid'];


        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'db');

        $user = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

        $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT likes FROM users WHERE user='".$user."'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $array = explode(" ", $row['likes']);
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            echo $value;
            echo $urlid;
            if($value == $urlid){
                echo "You liked this url already";
                break;
            }
            else{
            $array = $row['likes'];
            $array .= " ";
            $array .= "$urlid";
                $query = ("Update  users set likes = '".$array."' where user = '".$user."'");
                if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
                    echo "Data added!";
                }
                else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute sql: " . mysqli_error($con);

                }
            }
        }

        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're looping through *all* "likes" and comparing them.  So the sequence of steps is like this:

- Enter `2`
- No likes yet, so the data is added
- Enter `2`
- Loop over likes, find `2`, data was already added
- Enter `3`
- Loop over likes, find `2`, not match so data is added
- Enter `3`
- Loop over likes, find `2`, not match so data is added
- Continue looping, find `3`, data was already added

Correcting this is going to involve changing your design a bit.  Right now you have *one* de-normalized record with a string of space-delimited "likes".  Normalize your data.  Have one *record* per "like".  And instead of constantly updating a single record, insert new records.

Then when you want to see if a "like" already exists, you can use a `WHERE` clause.  Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=? AND like=?
```

(Note: This is using query parameters as a prepared statement.  This is *highly recommended*.  Your current code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.)

If any record is found at all, then the item was "already liked" and you can output the message.  If no record was found, `INSERT` a new one for that "like".

No need for a loop.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I have a problem understanding your solution. You say that for id=1 ex like=2 first. Then when 3 arrives a new record should be created, but I cannot do id=1 like=3 also. Or what do you mean by that?

Comment: @IrinaFarcau: It's not really clear what you're asking in that comment.  Basically the idea is that each discrete element of data should be separated (and non-repeated) in your database.  So each "like" would be its own record.  Any time a new one is added, `INSERT` a new record.  This table would then essentially be a many-to-many relationship between "users" and "things that can be liked".

Comment: I understand now. Thank youu